# How to identify columns of a table with multiple occurrences in R

Tags: r, string, datatable

If I have a table that contains a column of sequences (eg "GGGAAAGGGAAT), how could I select the rows in which "GGG" occurs multiple times in a single sequence. I have a table with hundreds of sequences. I have used the filter in RStudio to identify sequences with single occurrences of a word (eg. "GGG"); however, I am having difficulty identifying sequences with multiple occurrences of a word. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I'm glad you are not using Excel for this analysis ;)

```
# function to generate gene sequences
gene_gen <- function() return(paste0(sample(x = c('A','G','T'), size  = 12, replace = T),collapse=''))
# lets create a data table with a thousand of those  
df = data.table(replicate(1000,gene_gen()))
# select lines using a regular expression looking for two instances of GGG in the same sequence
df[regexpr('GGG.*GGG',V1)==1]
#Result is 
             V1
1: GGGGGAGGGGAG
2: GGGTATTGGGGT
3: GGGGAGAAGGGT
4: GGGTATGGGGTA
5: GGGTGTGGGAGG
6: GGGAGGGTGTTG
```

The key here is to use regular expressions. 
`regexpr('GGG.*GGG', sequence_string)` looks for 3 `GGG` characters, then anything (`.`) zero or more times (`*`) then 3 following `GGG` characters.
There are many online regex tester websites to help you train with them.